# How to replace fasta sequences in file1 from the second file2?

Tags: text-processing, awk, python, bioinformatics

I have two fasta files as shown below,

File1:

```
>Contig_1:90600-91187
AAGGCCATCAAGGACGTGGATGAGGTCGTCAAGGGCAAGGAACAGGAATTGATGACGGTC

>Contig_98:35323-35886
GACGAAGCGCTCGCCAAGGCCGAAGAAGAAGGCCTGGATCTGGTCGAAATCCAGCCGCAG

>Contig_24:26615-28387
GCTGCGGCGCTGATCCTGGCGGCCCGCGCCGAGGAGATCGCCCGTTTGGAGCGCGGCGAA
```

File2:

```
>Contig_1:90600-91187
GACCGTCATCAATTCCTGTTCCTTGCCCTTGACGACCTCATCCACGTCCTTGATGGCCTT

>Contig_24:26615-28387
TTCGCCGCGCTCCAAACGGGCGATCTCCTCGGCGCGGGCCGCCAGGATCAGCGCCG
```

Both files are having same fasta headers but varied with their sequences. I need to replace File2 sequences in File1 as shown below.

Expected outcome:

```
>Contig_1:90600-91187
GACCGTCATCAATTCCTGTTCCTTGCCCTTGACGACCTCATCCACGTCCTTGATGGCCTT

>Contig_98:35323-35886
GACGAAGCGCTCGCCAAGGCCGAAGAAGAAGGCCTGGATCTGGTCGAAATCCAGCCGCAG

>Contig_24:26615-28387
TTCGCCGCGCTCCAAACGGGCGATCTCCTCGGCGCGGGCCGCCAGGATCAGCGCCG
```

I tried with `cat` command, but it is concatenating all the sequences. But, I need to replace File1 sequences with File2 sequences.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR   { if(hdr){ hold[hdr]=$0; hdr="" }; if(/^>/) hdr=$0; next }
     ($0 in hold){ print $0 ORS hold[$0]; getline; next }
                 { print }' file2 file1
```